# Converting a linq query into an observablecollection

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq

I am trying to sort a linq problem.
I am binding data to a silverlight telerik silverlight graph but not having much luck. I am able to get the graph working with hardcoded values however when I try to bind it to a database no data is been returned.

This returns expected data.

```
  public class TranactionDetail
{
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public int TransactionType { get; set; }
    public double TransactionAmount { get; set; }
    public int Month{ get; set; }
    public string MonthName { get; set; }
    public double TransactionCount { get; set; }


    public static ObservableCollection<TranactionDetail> GetTransactions(int transactionType)
    {
        ObservableCollection<TranactionDetail> data;


        if (transactionType == 1)
        {
            data = new ObservableCollection<TranactionDetail>()
                       {
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 1,Month = DateTime.Now.Month,TransactionType = 1} ,
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 11,Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month,TransactionType = 1} ,
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 3,Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2).Month,TransactionType = 1} ,
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 1,Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3).Month,TransactionType = 1} ,
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 1,Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(4).Month,TransactionType = 1} ,
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 1,Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(5).Month,TransactionType = 1} ,
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 12,Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6).Month,TransactionType = 1} ,
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 1,Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(7).Month,TransactionType = 1} ,
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 1,Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(8).Month,TransactionType = 1} ,
                       };

        }
        else 
        {
            data = new ObservableCollection<TranactionDetail>()
            {
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 1,Month = DateTime.Now.Month,TransactionType = 2} ,
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 1,Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month,TransactionType = 2} ,
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 2,Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2).Month,TransactionType = 2} ,
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 5,Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3).Month,TransactionType = 2} ,
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 1,Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(4).Month,TransactionType = 2} ,
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 1,Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(5).Month,TransactionType =2} ,
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 1,Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6).Month,TransactionType = 2} ,
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 1,Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(7).Month,TransactionType = 2} ,
                        new TranactionDetail(){TransactionAmount = 7,Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(8).Month,TransactionType = 2} ,
            };
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Binding the graph like this

```
   List<ObservableCollection<TransactionDetail>> data = new List<ObservableCollection<ransactionDetail>>();
        data.Add(TransactionDetail.GetTransactions(1));
        data.Add(TransactionDetail.GetTransactions(3));         
        this.radChart.ItemsSource = data;
```

Xaml

```
<telerik:RadChart x:Name="radChart">
        <telerik:RadChart.DefaultView>
            <telerik:ChartDefaultView>
                <telerik:ChartDefaultView.ChartTitle>
                    <telerik:ChartTitle Content="Transaction Data" />
                </telerik:ChartDefaultView.ChartTitle>

            </telerik:ChartDefaultView>
        </telerik:RadChart.DefaultView>
        <telerik:RadChart.SeriesMappings>
            <telerik:SeriesMapping LegendLabel="Processed" CollectionIndex="0">
                <telerik:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
                    <telerik:LineSeriesDefinition ShowItemLabels="True" />
                </telerik:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
                <telerik:SeriesMapping.ItemMappings>
                    <telerik:ItemMapping DataPointMember="YValue" FieldName="TransactionAmount" />
                    <telerik:ItemMapping DataPointMember="XValue" FieldName="Month" />
                </telerik:SeriesMapping.ItemMappings>
            </telerik:SeriesMapping>
            <telerik:SeriesMapping LegendLabel="Redeemed" CollectionIndex="1">
                <telerik:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
                    <telerik:LineSeriesDefinition ShowItemLabels="True" />
                </telerik:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
                <telerik:SeriesMapping.ItemMappings>
                    <telerik:ItemMapping DataPointMember="YValue" FieldName="TransactionAmount" />
                    <telerik:ItemMapping DataPointMember="XValue" FieldName="Month"  />
                </telerik:SeriesMapping.ItemMappings>
            </telerik:SeriesMapping>
        </telerik:RadChart.SeriesMappings>
    </telerik:RadChart>
```

Now if I try binding the data to actual data like

```
 var grouped = from t in TransctionData
                      group t by new
                      {
                          t.PurchaseDate.Value.Month
                      }
                          into g
                          select new TransactionDetail()
                          {
                              Month = g.Select((n => n.PurchaseDate.Value.Month)).First(),
                              TransactionAmount = g.Count()
                          };


        List<ObservableCollection<TransactionDetail>> data = new     List<ObservableCollection<TransactionDetail>>();
        this.radChart.ItemsSource = grouped.ToList();
```

Nothing is been returned. I have placed a breakpoint and I can see this is values within grouped and they do look like TransactionDetail.

I am assuming that the first method using the observablecollection vs the 2nd using only the tolist() is the cause.

What do I need to change?

Comment: why are you selecting data in `RewardTransactionDetail` type where as your list takes `TransactionDetail` type.. do they share any inheritance relationship

Comment: Theres's something seriously wrong here. You're not using `data` in the second sample. And `group.ToList()` will return a `List<RewardTransactionDetail>`. There's no direct comparison to your first sample.

Comment: Hey Ani sorry I copied it over incorrectly. Updated now

Comment: Do you people ever bother yourself creating a simple code samples for you question or just copy-paste 100+ lines of unknown classes, functions, that are not even relevant to the question being asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified the SeriesMapping to the requirements based on the telerik userguide

Answer (score 0):

Hey There.
Instead of using .ToList()
can you Cast the 'grouped' with List>

```
this.radChart.ItemsSource = (List<ObservableCollection<TransactionDetail>>)grouped;
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Robbie,
I tried your suggestion however I get this error 
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.Int32],WebUI.Entry],Silverlight.TransactionDetail]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[Silverlight.TransactionDetail]]'.

Comment: Hey mate, i had this same problem a few weeks ago with the RadChart. have you tried removing the Observable Collection type completely from your code. I personally have found the Observable Collection type to be a pain when binding.

Comment: Yeah I tried binding it to just the grouped data however I am getting just the "No data series" display

Comment: Turns out it because my xaml was expecting 2 SeriesDefinitions and I was only providing 1